# Add an "Or do you believe this should actually be closed?" link/button when failing Close Vote audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Far too often I end up failing close vote reviews like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3136607) which I genuinely believe should be closed (in this case for "*demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*"). When this happens I'm greeted with a message titled:

> ## STOP! Look and Listen!

This is a pretty rude message to receive when you already were paying close attention to the question at hand. To make it worse I then have to click out of the review section to go into the question to cast the close vote I'd just attempted to add.

As someone who has obtained the silver Reviewer medal for Close Votes, could an "Or do you believe this should actually be closed?" link/button be added within the failed Close Vote audit message? This would allow us to cast a close vote after failing an audit like this instead of forcing us to leave the review process to do so.